# How to stop a Javascript alert from reappearing in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript

The alert dialog created in the onclick reappears every single time I dismiss it in an infinite loop. This occurs in both Chrome and Firefox. This is my first day learning Javascript so please be gentle.

Is there a way to make the alert dialog appear only once?

This might be a problem with my computer. If so, what do I do to fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>

<p>"The text should turn red and one alert dialog should appear on click."</p>

<script>
function changeFontRed() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.color = "red";
    console.log("Hello World!");
    window.alert("Hello World!");
    x.removeEventListener("onclick", changeFontRed(), false);
    x.addEventListener("onclick", changeFontBlue());
}

function changeFontBlue() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");           
    x.style.color = "blue";
    x.removeEventListener("onclick", changeFontBlue(), false);
    x.addEventListener("onclick", changeFontRed());
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="changeFontRed()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events the list of events you can use with addEventListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines:

```
x.removeEventListener("onclick", changeFontRed(), false);
x.addEventListener("onclick", changeFontBlue());
```

You are **calling the functions** `changeFontRed` and `changeFontBlue`, not **just naming them**. The parenthesis `()` mark an invocation, and when the function is called again the dialog reappears.

Also (thanks to commenters) the event is named "click". Try this:

```
x.removeEventListener("click", changeFontRed, false);
x.addEventListener("click", changeFontBlue);
```

Comment: add/removeEventListener wont work with 'onclick', just 'click'

Comment: Yes, it is important to change it to "click" not "onclick".

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` should be a function. You're not passing the function, you're **calling** the function because you have `()` after it. Take that out.

```
function changeFontBlue() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");           
    x.style.color = "blue";
    x.removeEventListener("click", changeFontBlue, false);
    x.addEventListener("click", changeFontRed);
}
```

Also, the name of the event is just `click`, not `onclick`.

Comment: add/removeEventListener wont work with 'onclick', just 'click'

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code, but the infinite loop problem is in the line below:

```
x.removeEventListener("onclick", changeFontRed(), false);
```

More specifically, that part: `changeFontRed()`. Although you're trying to remove the `changeFontRed` event listener off your element, what you're really doing is calling that function and passing the return value to the `removeEventListener` function. And as soon as you're already inside the `changeFontRead` function, it will be calling itself recursivelly, until it turns into a stack overflow.

---

The `removeEventListener` function expects as the second paramenter a function reference, that will be called only when the button is clicked. So, to fix your problem, you must remove the `()`, and pass the function itself. E.g: `removeEventListener('click', changeFontRed)`.

But there are other problems in your code, for example the `"onclick"` you're passing as the first parameter, because the `addEventListener` method won't understand it, since you shouldn't pass `"on[event name]"`, but only `"[event name]"`. So, it should be `"click"` only.

Answer (score 1):

1. the second argument for remove/addEventListener should be a function, not the result of calling the function (as answered already).
2. first argument for remove/addEventListener should be 'click' not 'onclick'.
3. The button click will work the first time only, after that, you click the text that changes colour to change the colour again.